# error android.os.networkonmainthreadexception asynctask getResponseCode

Tags: android

when run my code on the same class is app run good. but when i run this code on two class different, my app was error android.os.networkonmainthreadexception.
when debug i detect error at **responseHttp = httpConnection.getResponseCode();**
app run to line **responseHttp = httpConnection.getResponseCode();** and it go to catch{},it cancel "If..else".And log error android.os.networkonmainthreadexception.
Can you help me!!

My code class Asynctask

```
package com.example.finishdemo;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class TestConnectionNew extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private int responseHttp = 0;
private String flag="false";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urltest) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urltest[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        **responseHttp = httpConnection.getResponseCode();**
        if (responseHttp == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            flag = "true";
        } else {
            flag = "false";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Thong bao loi: "+e.toString());
    }
    return flag;
}
}
```

Code class main:

```
package com.example.finishdemo;
public class Hoadon extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hoadon);
    TestConnectionNew t=new TestConnectionNew();
    String recieve=t.doInBackground("http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php");
    if(recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
    {
        doTimerTask();
    }else
        if(recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
    {
        showAlert("Không kết nối được đến server hoặc thiết bị chưa có kết nối internet!");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is how you need to invoke a AsyncTask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [asynctask.execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) for executing AsyncTask instead of calling doInBackground manually   as:

```
 TestConnectionNew t = new TestConnectionNew();
 t.execute("http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php");
```

Change your TestConnectionNew as

```
public class TestConnectionNew extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private int responseHttp = 0;
private String flag="false";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urltest) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urltest[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        **responseHttp = httpConnection.getResponseCode();**
        if (responseHttp == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            flag = "true";
        } else {
            flag = "false";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Thong bao loi: "+e.toString());
    }
    return flag;
}

@Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String recieve) {
           if(recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
               doTimerTask();
           }else
           if(recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
             {
              showAlert("Không kết nối được đến server hoặc thiết bị chưa có kết nối internet!");
             }
      }
}
```

and for more help about how we use  AsyncTask see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: When i add code "String recieve=t.execute("http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php");" and recieve this notication "Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,Void,String> to String"

Comment: @user1817079 : see my edit answer for updating UI you will need to Override onPostExecute

Comment: and if you use String recieve=t.execute("longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php").get(); then this will also hang UI Thread until control is not returned from AsyncTask to main Thread

Comment: thank you...i use String recieve=t.execute("longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php").get(); and run success...

Comment: @user1817079 : don't use get() if you want to make request in background without wait see here when we use execute.get(); http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29

Comment: if don't use get(),so i should use function?

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml 
you add a code:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```